# Error connecting to remote server using http webrequest (converting from php curl)

Tags: c#, .net, curl

I am currently trying to test a php curl script using a simple c# application (http webrequest class). 155.00.11.22:1111 is supposed to be a proxy server that will route the message to destination X.

I have tried two ways, by creating a request directly to the ip like in the php, and setting the ip as a webproxy, both shows "unable to connect to remote server". There is nothing wrong with the server as the php script runs perfectly. So, I need some advice on what might cause my c# script unable to connect to the remote server. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

PHP curl script:

```
$data = "<msg><id>PEOPLE</id><loc>LOCATION</loc><ppl>STAFF</ppl></msg>";
$url = 'http://155.00.11.22:1111';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1 );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Content-Type: text/plain')); 
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

My C#:

```
Uri testuri = new Uri("http://155.00.11.22:1111");
string postData = "<msg><id>PEOPLE</id><loc>LOCATION</loc><ppl>STAFF</ppl></msg>";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(testuri);
request.Method = "POST";
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
request.ContentType = "text/plain";
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
dataStream.Close();
```

Comment: What happens when you execute `telnet 155.00.11.22 1111` in the CMD prompt?

Comment: It returns could not open connection to the host, on port 1111 : Connect failed.

Okay,I am quite new with the networking stuff, why is it that I can't connect to that server from Windows and yet I can launch the php script which is able to communicate with the server?

Comment: That's a fantastic question.  You are invoking both programs from the same machine (and, if applicable, the same VM)?

Comment: Actually I executed the php script online, @ http://www.compileonline.com/execute_php_online.php (I will try it on my own pc later)

But, is there a difference? I mean, the fact that I launched the php script online. The message is still routed to destination X and from my own c# application I could not connect to the server.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that there's no doubgt about the issue.Server originally are set to accept tcip connection on port 80 or 8080.I think that this port is not enable to accept inbound connection from external ip for security reason. Have you try to make the same call to 155.00.11.22:80 or 8080 and also where the page to call is the default page within domain ?If you are not able from local machine to ping that ip it means that connections from remote to that port are not allowed.
check this network issue before test your script.

Comment: I see...I've tested the php script on my local machine and it could not be connected to the server either, the only time it works was when i ran the script online. I will discuss with the person that manages the server and post a follow-up in this thread.

Comment: Your script is working under a domain name?If it is pass as uri ("http://domainname.ext/yourpage.php") and it will done more simple and accurate and if you do it it will work coz the uri post data directly to php script too.Take a try and let me know

Comment: I don't quite understand about the term "working under a domain name", but basically for my testing on local machine, i created a php file from the php script above and save it as testing.php. Then I just use CMD prompt "php testing.php" to run it. But the message is not sent to destination X (Destination X is in the same domain I assume with ip of 155.00.11.264).

I am still a little bit confuse on why the php script runs perfectly on a online compiler such as http://www.compileonline.com/execute_php_online.php.

Is my local testing method wrong? Please advice.

Comment: why are you not checking all this in local environment using localhost ?

Comment: Because the proxy server and the page to call from the proxy server is developed by different people in another country. However, I will take note of your comment regarding the port and shall discuss with them.

Comment: It seems the problem is still there, I tried two different local machines and both are unable to connect to the remote server, and it seems the remote server isn't blocking any incoming connection.

And it works perfectly if i compile the source code online. That is what I could not understand. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you mean that if you test your code from  compileonline.com/execute_php_online.php or did you intend from the live server ?Coz the server is executing the call it self and so not block the request.The issue is related from external sources.Is all ips enable to ping machine? is it that ip real so i can try to ping it via cmd?

Comment: with direct ping it fails and it seems just one stuff network issue.If a server is online and i ping it or give me a reject or even it succeed and in my case it fail.

Comment: have you team viewer so i can take a look with you from your local machine? if yes send me a contact request via skype to turri.giorgio so we can write on skype in real time and check via teamviewer too which is more faster

Comment: Okay,due to the fact that this is related to some work thingy, I need to see if I could share out the real ip.

I did not run the script from the server itself, I test both PHP and C# code on compileonline.com and I manage to connect to the server. Just that using the same PHP and C# scripts, I tried executing on any PC but it won't work (unable to connect to remote host). The server is live.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51751/discussion-between-ytan-and-makemoney2010)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem  and I realize my IP address was changed. I was using the Wamp with Apache installed on it.